# Migrating from SVN to Git with large history

Tags: git, svn, github, svn2git

I'm trying to migrate a large project from SVN to Git. It's a +15 years old project and it has a large history. We are using the svn2git Ruby tool, but can't push to the repo because the history file is +1GB, therefore get an error message.

Is it possible to enable LFS support to the history files, or any other way to keep the history?

Also, is there a way to migrate only the last 4 branches and 4 tags, instead of all the branches and tags?

Comment: We migrated an even bigger svn repository to git without LFS and it worked. What is actually the error message that keeps you from pushing the repository?

Comment: Thank you for response. I don't remember the exact message, but I can try again as soon as possible and post it.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty tools called `svn2git`, but from your question I see you are not using the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

You will easily be able to configure it for your layout to get the result you want and expect.

Also just porting specific branches is easy as pie by configuring the branches you want explicitly and use a catch-all for the rest that does not forward to a repository.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of a SVN repository when migrating it to Git.